# Cascade Saves with Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

How do I "turn on" cascading saves using AutoMap Persistence Model with Fluent NHibernate?

As in:

I Save the Person and the Arm should also be saved. Currently I get

> *"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"*

```
public class Person : DomainEntity
{
  public virtual Arm LeftArm { get; set; }
}

public class Arm : DomainEntity
{
  public virtual int Size { get; set; }
}
```

**I found [an article on this topic](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/11/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-entity-conventions/), but it seems to be outdated.**

Comment: Would this be done using a convention?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works with the new configuration bits. For more information, see http://fluentnhibernate.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_to_new_style_conventions

```
//hanging off of AutoPersistenceModel    
.ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<CascadeAll>()


public class CascadeAll : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
{
    public bool Accept( IOneToOnePart target )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Apply( IOneToOnePart target )
    {
        target.Cascade.All();
    }

    public bool Accept( IOneToManyPart target )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Apply( IOneToManyPart target )
    {
        target.Cascade.All();
    }

    public bool Accept( IManyToOnePart target )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Apply( IManyToOnePart target )
    {
        target.Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually used Kristoffers shorter example but I am sure this one works too

Answer (score 13):

Updated for use with the the current version:

```
public class CascadeAll : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.All();
    }

    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.All();
    }

    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: For "public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
", I also find it useful to have "instance.inverse();" in addition to "instance.Cascade.All()."

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've found to do this for a whole project is to use **DefaultCascade**:

```
.Conventions.Add( DefaultCascade.All() );
```

Go to ["The Simplest Conventions"](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) section on the wiki, for this, and a list of others.

Here's the list from the Wiki:

```
Table.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Table")
PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => "ID")
AutoImport.Never()
DefaultAccess.Field()
DefaultCascade.All()
DefaultLazy.Always()
DynamicInsert.AlwaysTrue()
DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue()
OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.Dirty())
Cache.Is(x => x.AsReadOnly())
ForeignKey.EndsWith("ID")
```

A word of warning - some of the method names in the Wiki may be wrong.  I edited the Wiki with what I could verify (i.e. DefaultCascade and DefaultLazy), but can't vouch for the rest.  But you should be able to figure out the proper names with Intellisense if the need arises.

Comment: I'd love to see that link, but it's dead

Comment: @Joel: looks like the new wiki is here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions

Answer (score 3):

The Convention Method Signatures have changed. For the new answer that does exactly what this question asks see [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242902/cascade-saves-with-fluent-nhibernate-automapping-old-anwser-still-valid).

Answer (score 1):

You can also make cascading the default convention for all types. For example (using the article you linked to as a starting point):

```
autoMappings.WithConvention(c =>  
  {  
    // our conventions
    c.OneToOneConvention = o => o.Cascade.All();
    c.OneToManyConvention = o => o.Cascade.All();
    c.ManyToOneConvention = o => o.Cascade.All();
  });
```