# Can NHibernate be configured fluently to delete children when their references are set to null?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've heard this can also be accomplished with triggers, but I'd rather not go that road if I can.  Right now it seems like nulling references to child objects just leaves them orphaned in the database, which isn't ideal to say the least.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the cascade option to delete orphans:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId").AsBag().Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

To make this work you need to remove the child object from the parent's collection and flush the session:

```
using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    parent.Children.Remove(child);
    txn.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Fluent.NH here but I know you can specify the cascade type for a mapping.  Setting it to all-delete-orphan should do what you're asking.

If you're using convention based configuration this should give you a starting point..

[Cascade Saves with Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586888/cascade-saves-with-fluent-nhibernate-automapping)